# Como executar uma função após AngularJS renderizar o conteúdo no template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Gostaria de chamar uma função após o AngularJS renderizar o conteúdo no template, assim como ele remove o `display:none` quando se usa o `ng-cloak`.

```
function executaAposRenderizar(){...}
app.controller('lista', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.itens = [...]
    // executaAposRenderizar();
}])
```

Como chamar uma função após o AngularJS ter imprimido o conteúdo no template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

```
app.directive('executarAposRenderizar', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                scope.$evalAsync(attr.executarAposRenderizar);
            }
        }
    }
});

app.controller('lista', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.itens = [...]
    $scope.alerta = function(){console.log('sucesso');};
}])
```

HTML:

```
<ul ng-app="app" ng-controller="lista">
    <li ng-repeat="item in itens" executar-apos-renderizar="alerta()">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Após executar o ultimo item do loop é chamado o `alerta()` do `$scope` através do `executar-apos-renderizar`.

Referências:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished
- http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/W8nhv/

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar o `timeout$` para colocar a função na lista de eventos do browser.

```
function executaAposRenderizar(){...}
app.controller('lista', ['$scope','$timeout', function($scope,$timeout) {
    $scope.itens = [...]
    $timeout(executaAposRenderizar, 0);

}])
```